# CTRL+F not working with the with virtual scroll bar of angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-directives

I am facing issue with CTRL + F functionality of browser while using virtual scroll bar. Let me explain it with an example-Suppose I am having a list of say ten thousand data and I want to use, search in the page( i.e. ctrl +f) functionality of browser to search data that might be present at the end of the list. So, using ctrl+f to search that data is not working on the list. If anybody has solution then please help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is someone comment in this [link](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/419)

Ctrl+F causes the window to lose the focus without fire a "onkeyup" to release the Ctrl key lock. I solved it by adding the third event below:

```
self.bind(document,"keydown",function(e){
  var ctrl = e.ctrlKey||false;
  if (ctrl) self.wheelprevented = true;
});
self.bind(document,"keyup",function(e){
  var ctrl = e.ctrlKey||false;
    if (!ctrl) self.wheelprevented = false;
});
self.bind(window,"blur",function(e){
  self.wheelprevented = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser search can not work in this case, because virtual scroll remove elements from DOM.
Browser search work on dom elements. Browser seach will only work on elements wchich are in DOM.